# Django - minify javascript files

Tags: javascript, django, minify

I would like to minify my javascripts. I saw page https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/ and checked first few libraries. It seems to me that those packages are overcomplicated for my case. I have not found a tutorial how to achieve simple scenario like

1. minify my javacript files (probably during collectstatic, or as admin action)
2. replace javascripts in my templates with its minified versions

I will probably have just one file per page, so there is really no reason for compressing.

Can you give me advice, what library/tutorial I should follow to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Well, maybe this [gist](https://gist.github.com/btimby/1870959) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) is the main tool for this, I think. As your use case sounds pretty simple, I think it'll be sufficient.

If your Javascript becomes very complex, it'd be best to work with Javascript asset pipeline tools and try to fit them into Django, this area is not Django's strong point.

Examples (and the rest of the docs) at [read the docs](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#examples).

Comment: Link is not working. I am pretty sure that django-compressor could do that, I check briefly the documentation, but I was hoping for simpler solution, or tutorial how exactly use django-compressor in this minimal way.

Comment: I added a link to the examples in the docs, I think it's really quite straightforward, hope this helps

Comment: Can Django-compressor rename javascript variable names and functions to minify the file further? Can Django-compressor make the whole javascript file into 1 line to make it harder to read?

Answer (score -1):

Try this?

http://jscompress.com/

Or this?

https://javascript-minifier.com/

Source: Google search term: minify javascript

Comment: If I am correct, it is know package usable by Django.